# Unable to add a logic to sort with dates in the existing comparator in Java/android

Tags: java, android, sorting, date, comparator

I want to add a condition that also sorts according to the DATE (desc order) of the item.startReading.
`item.startReading` value has the date value in the string format `2018-10-20T12:05:41`. But I have no clue how to 
add this logic to the current code. Before the user clicks the magazine or the book item, the value of `item.startReading` is `null`.
. When the user clicks the either one of the items, I want the newest `item.startReading` to go to the top like the following.
Sorry for my explanation, but I really need to know how to do since I started learning java/android. Some examples or tips would be lovely.
I would love to hear from you.

3. magazine (2018-10-21T13:06:41) newest date item to go to the top
4. magazine (2018-10-20T12:05:41)
5. books
6. books

Currently, I have the following comparator code that does the sorting like below.

(Before using the comparator)

4. magazine
5. books
6. magazine
7. books

(After the using the comparator)
reoders with type and finally with the ID
↓

1. books
2. books
3. magazine
4. magazine

My comparator code:

```
public Comparator<MyItem> myComparator = (item1, item2) -> {
    //How to add the desc date order with Dates?

    if (item1.typeInt == MyItemModel.TYPE_BOOK && item2.typeInt !=  MyItemModel.TYPE_BOOK) {
        return -1;
    } else if (item1.type !=  MyItemModel.TYPE_BOOK && item2.type ==  MyItemModel.TYPE_BOOK) {
        return 1;
    } else if (item1.type == MyItemModel.TYPE_MAGAZINE && item2.type != MyItemModel.TYPE_MAGAZINE) {
        return -1;
    } else if (item1.type != MyItemModel.TYPE_MAGAZINE && item2.type == MyItemModel.TYPE_MAGAZINE) {
        return 1;
    } 
    return (Integer.compare((int) item1.id, (int) item2.id)) * -1;
};
```

Comment: As i  understood from your question, you are having  item objects with date property and you want to sort according to date DESC . date as null value must appear last??

Comment: When the user doesn't click the item the item.startReading has the null value so it should be skipped. I want the item to go to the top only when the date has the value, when the item is clicked I want the newest item to be stacked on the top, sorry for my bad explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a function which parse given date

```
public Date parseDateFromString(String date){
    if(date == null) {
        return null;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-yy'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    try {
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then compare it with Comparator like

```
if (item1.typeInt != item2.typeInt) {
    return item1.typeInt == MyItemModel.TYPE_MAGAZINE ? 1 : -1;
} else {
    if (parseDateFromString(item1.getStartReading()) == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (parseDateFromString(item2.getStartReading()) == null) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return parseDateFromString(item2.getStartReading()).after(parseDateFromString(item1.getStartReading())) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only please don’t try to teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Today we have so much better in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for your suggestion. I am also beginner. can you suggest me which Date time class to use in API level 19 (android). I have tried `DateTimeFormatter` But it required API level 26.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that this was an Android question and answered it as a Java question. However, `DateTimeFormatter` and the other classes from java.time are available for lower level Android in [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), so you may still give it thought. That will be my suggestion (also I believe the asker has a higher level and can probably use the built-in java.time; I agree that it will be interesting to have answers for other levels too).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Comparator<MyItem> myComparator
        // books first; sort by a Boolean expression that is false for books to put them first
        = Comparator.comparing((MyItem it) -> it.type != MyItemModel.TYPE_BOOK)
                // then magazines first
                .thenComparing(it -> it.type != MyItemModel.TYPE_MAGAZINE)
                // then by start date-time, nulls last, otherwise newest first
                .thenComparing(it -> it.startReading,
                        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing((String start)
                                -> LocalDateTime.parse(start)).reversed()))
                // then by ID
                .thenComparing(it -> it.id);
```

Since your API level is high enough for lambdas, I assume that you can also use `Comparator.comparing` and `thenComparing`, etc. Do that. It’s not only terser, it is also less error-prone. I suspect that you intended `type` rather than `typeInt` in your code, at least it’s not consistent, an inconsistency that you simply cannot make with `comparing`.

`Comparator.nullsLast` sorts `null` values last (there is a sister method `nullsFirst` in case you want that). Your string of `2018-10-21T13:06:41` is in ISO 8601 format, the format that `LocalDateTime` parses as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter. We should of course take advantage of this fact. `reversed` reverses the order of the comparator so the newest rather than the oldest items come first.

EDIT: With inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52707675/5772882) I am sorting Booleans for getting the books and then magazines first. In the natural ordering of Booleans false comes before true. I sort on `it.type != MyItemModel.TYPE_BOOK`, which will be false for books, that is, they come first, and true for everything else. Next I do similarly for magazines.

**Further possible improvements**

- Declare getters for your attributes and use `MyItem::getId` rather than `it -> it.id`.
- Store `startReading` as a `LocalDateTime` rather than a string inside your `MyItem`, so you don’t need to parse for each comparison (there are many other reasons why this is a good idea). Just format it into a `String` when you need to present it to the user.