# Sort Java collection relative to the current date

Tags: java, android, sorting, date, collections

I want to sort my List of Date relative to the current date, e.g we have next items in list:

```
10.01.2018, 
10.20.2018, 
10.14.2018, 
10.02.2018
```

and the current date is `10.08.2018`.

The result should be ascending sort of array in the next order:

```
10.14.2018, 
10.20.2018    and then 
10.01.2018, 
10.02.2018.
```

First should be dates that didn't happen and then the past dates. How to do it with Comparator?

Comment: Add today's date to the list and sort in descending order like you would do with any other list. Either this or I didn't understand your question.

Comment: What have you tried? You write a `Comparator` that does just what you said. Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to know more.

Comment: I meant that dates before should be ascending and dates after should ascending too, e.g today is oct. 8 and list that includes oct. 10, 1, 2, 12, 15, 4 should be sort as: oct. 10, 12, 15 (dates after today in ascending order) and oct. 1, 2, 4 (past dates also in ascending order), so the list should looks like 10, 12, 15, 1, 2, 4. I don't know how to do it at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this way

- if the two dates you're comparing are on the same side (both before or both after) of today, compare them normally
- if you have one before and one after you need to reverse the order

This will keep `ascending order` but put future dates before past dates

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<LocalDate> list = Arrays.asList(
                                      LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 1), LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 20),
                                      LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 14),LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 2));
    System.out.println(list);
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

    list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1.isBefore(now) && o2.isBefore(now) || o1.isAfter(now) && o2.isAfter(now)) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    });

    System.out.println(list);
}


[2018-10-01, 2018-10-20, 2018-10-14, 2018-10-02]
[2018-10-14, 2018-10-20, 2018-10-01, 2018-10-02]
```

Answer (score 7):

The most concise and elegant, yet readable way I've found is as follows:

```
list.sort(
    Comparator
    .comparing( LocalDate.now()::isAfter )
    .thenComparing( Comparator.naturalOrder() )
);
```

This reads as *sort by first comparing whether each date is after today or not, then break ties using `LocalDate`'s natural order*. (It's worth remembering that sorting `boolean` values means putting `false`s at the beginning and `true`s at the end, i.e. `false < true`).

Comment: That `Comparator.comparing(LocalDate.now()::isAfter)` is a little bit tricky, but very pleasing once you’ve understood it. It’s for lack of a `comparingBoolean`. I’ll remember, but will probably insert an explaining comment if I use it in my own code. Thanks for explaining thoroughly in the answer.

Comment: mb it's the best and brief answer but I forgot to say it should work on android so ill only upvote your answer, sorry

Comment: Nice answer ! I tried to think about something like this but I didn't find it, great !

Answer (score 3):

```
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

    List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.asList(
            LocalDate.parse("2018-10-02"),
            LocalDate.parse("2018-10-20"),
            LocalDate.parse("2018-10-14"),
            LocalDate.parse("2018-10-01"));

    // sort relative to the current date
    dates.sort(Comparator.<LocalDate>comparingInt(localDate ->
            localDate.isAfter(now) ? -1 : localDate.isBefore(now) ? 1 : 0)
            // then sort normally
            .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

    System.out.println(dates);
```

Comment: Wonderful. Very good application of `LocalDate` and `Comparator`.